# gcc naked атрибут

Tags: c, компилятор, gcc, g++

Приветствую всех.
А я к вам снова с вопросом:)

Ковыряю gcc, к своему сожалению обнаружил что для архитектур i386 amd64 не поддерживается naked атрибут.

Ну и собственно вопросы:

1. Есть ли возможность обойти это досадное недоразумение (может я проглядел какие-нибудь специфичные для этих архитектур атрибуты)
2. Может кто-то знает - есть ли в отсутствии этого атрибута какой-то злой или добрый умысел со стороны разработчиков? (короче - почему атрибут не поддерживается?)

Большое спасибо за ваши ответы.

Comment: Да, действительно интересно, почему для некоторых архитектур naked (минимальные пролог и эпилог функции) поддерживаются, а для х86 нет?

Рискну предположить, что в архитектурах, для которых разрешен атрибут naked *машинная инструкция CALL сама* обеспечивает связывание фреймов вызовов функций.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Может быть обычная лень тому причина.

- [Equivalent of __declspec( naked ) in gcc/g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937536/equivalent-of-declspec-naked-in-gcc-g)
- [Naked functions in gcc/g++](http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=15) - здесь есть обходные пути.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вторая ссылка самое то, буду разбираться